# WPF ListBox loads lots of pics will got System.IO.IOException occured in PresentationCore.dll?

Tags: wpf, windows, listbox

My ItemTemplate is very Simple, One `TextBlock` to show **Name**, Another `Image` to show **Net Image**：

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Url, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource cvtImage}}" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my pictrues array:

```
private int[] numArr =
{
    20333581,
    65476272,
    65494751,
    67810732,
    72685857,
    73794129,
    74292128,
    78448608,
    89297529,
    109457648,
    128775798,
    136864278,
    140889893,
    155315730,
    155707244,
    158590544,
    160382605,
    162265810,
    167648987,
    170883246,
    175708510,
    181177782,
};

private List<ImageItem> imagesList = new List<ImageItem>();
private int imageCount = 22;


private void initialImageList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
    {
        imagesList.Add(new ImageItem {
            Name = "item " + (i + 1).ToString(),
            Url = String.Format("https://p.qlogo.cn/gh/{0}/{0}_1/40", numArr[i], numArr[i])
        });
    }
}
```

**Net Images above are all valid.**
Class `ImageItem` is simple with two Properties: `Name` and `Url`
Here is my **converter** class:

```
class GcToNetImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var url = (string)value;
        Console.WriteLine("url is " + url);
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ex message: {0}", ex.Message);
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Aftet setting `lb.ItemsSource = this.imagesList;`,
when you slide down the ListBox, you will definitely got `IOException`.

I guess it's something about with memory leak

Comment: Can you post the cvtImage Converter please?

Comment: @richej I've posted the Converter

Comment: Item 170883246 is the problem.. No Idea whats wrong with it.

Comment: @richej no, I can get `https://p.qlogo.cn/gh/170883246/170883246_1/40` image

Comment: yea, I know but it is causing the problem anyway. When you remove it it works. I figured it out by first loading all bytes of an image and then converting the byte[] to a bitmap. This last step fails for this particular image..

Comment: @richej you are right, it is causing the problem, maybe it can not be converted to `Bitmap`. And How to solve this problem? any good advice?